# vimrc test for if_lua during vundle BundleInstall

Tags: vim, lua, vundle

I use the same .vimrc file on lots of systems.  I'd like to bypass vundle installing some modules that I know won't work if 'if_lua' is not present.

Is there a vim script way of conditionally doing

```
Bundle 'Shougo/neocomplete.vim'
```

only if vim was compiled with lua to avoid the start up error:

```
$ vim myprogram.c
neocomplete does not work this version of Vim.
It requires Vim 7.3.885 or above and "if_lua" enabled Vim.
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

thx

Comment: The cool thing about vim plugins is you can read their source code. You can find how neocomplete checks this by opening `neocomplete/plugin/neocomplete.vim` and searching for the error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if has('lua')
    Bundle 'Shougo/neocomplete.vim'
end
```